# How to use GPU on Jupyter notebook in Google Cloud AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu

I'm using a GPU-enabled Jupyter notebook on the Google Cloud AI Platform.

However, despite being GPU enabled, it is only using the CPU when I train my machine learning model.

Does anyone know how I can make it use GPU instead? I've been using Google Colab notebooks before this, and there you can simply change the runtime to use GPU in the menu at the top of the notebook. But it doesn't look like there is an option like that in the Jupyter notebook.

Appreciate any advice on how to get it to use GPU!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AI Platform Notebooks don't have the drivers pre-installed. When you [create an AI Platform Notebooks instance](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#create_an_instance_with_default_properties), if you choose to include a GPU, you must select the option to **Install NVIDIA GPU driver automatically for me** so the image is provisioned the latest stable driver based on the framework's CUDA version.

[image]

Comment: User-maintained notebooks are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the GCP [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/manage-hardware-accelerators) you can attach GPU on the Jupyter Notebook. First of all, you need to stop the notebook instance then select the GPU's from the GPU column along with the number of accelerators. After AI Platform Notebooks has finished updating the GPUs for your notebook instance, you can start the instance by selecting your instance and then clicking Start.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! The GPU column says that there is one GPU, but it still isn't using GPU since the calculations run really slowly, and I only see CPU utlisation in the Compute Engine details. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Did you [install](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu) the GPU driver?

Comment: Thanks! No I haven't installed any GPU drivers. Is that necessary for AI Platform notebooks? I had a look at the documentation, and it says:

Pro Tip: Alternatively, you can skip this setup by creating VMs with Deep Learning VM images. Deep Learning VM images have NVIDIA drivers pre-installed...

AI Platform Notebooks makes it easy to manage JupyterLab instances through a protected, publicly available notebook instance URL. A JupyterLab instance is a Deep Learning virtual machine...

Or have I missed something?

Comment: using that [doc](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-gpu-enabled-vm-on-gcp-to-train-your-neural-networks-1491ae087e79) I tested that GPU attached to my test instance working properly.